# Opening Podcasts App from My App not landing on Library tab

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I want to open `Podcasts` from my app and it should land on Library tab.

I have tried the url-scheme:

> "pcast://"

but it redirects to `Browser` page inside `Podcasts` and shows error "*Can't connect right now*". Please see the image below.

[image]

The desired behaviour is - It should land on Library tab. Please see the image below.

[image]

I have already searched a lot and couldn't find anything.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where did you find the reference to `pcast://` in the first place? I can't find any public documentation around Podcasts at all, so would it have further information there on parameters for deep linking?

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/
Check this link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the shared link from Podcast?

1. Launch `Podcast`
2. Click on `Library`
3. Select one
4. Click on `...` button
5. Select `Share`
6. Select `Copy Link`

And use this link?

The following seems to work for me

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/podcast/newshour/id356157099?l=en&mt=2")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: I don't want to open any podcast, I just want it to land on library.
We don't have any channel, we just have a list of episodes.